# Not work in auto generated but work when I manual coding?

Tags: java, image, swing, label

This is so frustrated. The code only work on manual generated but not work in auto generate ???
There is an image in project "Bird.png".

```
public ComboBox() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Bird.png"));
        lblShow = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

This is my manual generate code :

```
    public MainFrame(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,400);
    //create new panel and add panel to frame
    JPanel pnlImg=new JPanel();
    add(pnlImg);
    //create new label for showing image
    JLabel lblShowImg;

    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(300,300,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    lblShowImg=new JLabel(ii);


    /*add label to panel */
    pnlImg.add(lblShowImg);

    /* show frame*/
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @91378246 : Auto means you create new JFrame Form in netbeans. Manual means you Write it normally.

Comment: `but not work` Can you define what you mean by 'not work'?

Comment: @copeg the label not showing anything.

Comment: 1) You don't prove to us that you're looking in the right places for the image (does it work ever for the bird image?). 2) Most importantly, you're not taking layout managers into consideration. NetBeans likely uses GroupLayout or absolute positioning, and this will not be friendly towards you're adding a new JLabel to the GUI.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tested both of them in the same project, and only the 2nd one works. I debugged and it run without throwing null in image.

Comment: OK then what container are you adding the JLabel to in the generated code, and **what layout manager is it using**?

Comment: And **Where** do you add the JLabel to anything in the generated class? You never show it. You were likely down-voted for asking an incomplete question, one without enough information to answer well without guessing.

Comment: You need to post a valid [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Why is this not working?

```
public ComboBox() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Bird.png"));
        lblShow = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Likely due to your not taking layout managers into account, but the truth is, as written it is impossible to say

- You never show where you add the JLabel to any container
- You don't indicate what layout manager the container is using
- You haven't posted a valid [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

To possibly solve this --

- allow NetBeans to generate a JPanel
- Add your JLabel to your own JPanel, one whose layout you control.
- Add both to a JFrame (respecting its contentPane's layout) that you display.